# Predict Sales as Counterfactual for Experiment

Tags: python, r, time-series, lstm, prediction

Which modelling strategy (time frame, features, technique) would you recommend to forecast 3-month sales for total customer base?

At my company, we often analyse the effect of e.g. marketing campaigns that run at the same time for the total customer base. In order to get an idea of the true incremental impact of the campaign, we - among other things - want to use predicted sales as a counterfactual for the campaign, i.e. what sales were expected to be assuming no marketing campaign.

1. **Time frame** used to train the model I'm currently considering 2 options (**static time frame and rolling window) - let me know what you think**. 1. Static: Use the same period last year as the dependent variable to build a specific model for this particular 3 month time frame. Data of 12 months before are used to generate features. 2. Use a rolling window logic of 3 months, dynamically creating dependent time frames and features. Not yet sure what the benefit of that would be. It uses more recent data for the model creation but feels less specific because it uses any 3 month period in a year as dependent. Not sure what the theory says for this particular example. Experiences, thoughts?
2. **Features** - currently building features per customer from one year pre-period data, e.g. Sales in individual months, 90,180,365 days prior, max/min/avg per customer, # of months with sales, tenure, etc. Takes quite a lot of time - any libraries/packages you would recommend for this?
3. **Modelling technique** - currently considering **GLM, XGboost, S/ARIMA, and LSTM networks. Any experience here?**

To clarify, even though I'm considering e.g. ARIMA, I do not need to predict any seasonal patterns of the 3 month window. As a first stab, a single number, total predicted sales of customer base for these 3 months, would be sufficient.

**Any experience or comment would be highly appreciated.**

Thanks,
F

Comment: This is a question better suited to the stats StackExchange site [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, you're right, will migrate the question.